# How to create a mathematical model out of my data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, regression, modeling

I have two sets of data `x` and `y` which give me another set of data `z`. 
It means, there is a function `f(x,y)=z`.
How can I model this in MATLAB? What kind of model should I pick? 
How can I determine the function `f(x,y)`?

Comment: You should at least know the type of function that you're trying to fit (for example: linear, quadratic, exponential, sinusoidal,...) then you can use `lsqcurvefit`in order to determine the coefficients of your function. Why can't you find directly the whole function ? Because your data can be fitted by way more than one function (for example with a fourier series you can almost fit every continuous function)

Comment: If you would please post a link to the data, I will run it through my online curve and surface fitting web site's "function finder" and see what it turns up for a z = f(x,y) model.

Comment: `f = @(x,y) mean(zdata(:));`. As far as the information provided in the question can indicate, this is a perfectly adequate model of your data. Describing any observations you may have about its performance may help identify what objectives you really have for your model.

Comment: @obchardon What do you mean by finding directly the whole function? And my problem is I have no idea about the type of the function. So, I cannot use `lsqcurvefit`

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: What you're asking for is simply impossible.

Why ? Because your `data z` can be fitted by more than one function `f(x,y)`. 
And even if one function fit your `data z` better than another one, it won't necessary mean that this function is the model that will be able to fit `z` if you have new data `x` and `y`.

What are your options:

- You can **fit** your data by

  - 1. trying to apply tousands of well known function/model and see what model suit the best your data (here you can use `lsqcurvefit` to adjust the constant of each function/model
  - 2. trying to apply a Taylor serie or a Fourier serie.
- You start to understand how interact your variables `x` and `y` to produce `z` in order to develop your own model that will be based on physical/economical/... assumptions.

I think that you're confusing "fitting the data" with "get a perfect model that will totally explain your data"

Comment: As I understand it, your option 1 cannot work for well known non-linear equations and can only be applied to linear equations. Is this correct?

Comment: I've never said that it can only work for linear equation ? Do I ?

Comment: By the way, i've tried the zunzun fitting engine ;) really nice work! But in this case, where OP have no idea of which model rules his results, it can be dangerous to use such a technic because it can lead to choose a wrong model just because those particular data fit well with a particuliar equation.

Comment: In any "equation search" or "function finder" use where the actual underlying relationship in the data is unknown, the best solutions are the ones with the fewest parameters. My web site's function finder allows starting the search using equations with few parameters and then increasing the parameter count in the search. At a minimum, the site might suggest a possible direction for thought regarding the unknown relationship in the data. By the way, the site is open source with source code links at the bottom of every page.